# Eclipse: How to make build-config variables available at compile time?

Tags: eclipse

In an Arduino project, I have build configurations to compile for, and download to, two devices: an Arduino Mega2560 and a standalone ATmega 328P DIP chip on a breadboard.  Both configs compile, download and run on their respective devices, at least for device independent code like a Hello program.  But most programs, f/ex, blinky, would need some conditional device-dependent code.  I could make up and define some symbols on (Project Properties > C/C++ Build > AVR Compiler (and AVR C++ Compiler) > Symbols) per configuration, which would get added to the compiler command-lines.

But somewhere within the IDE, the part and other choices I selected for each configuration are known and assigned to environment variables in (Project Properties > C/C++ Build > Environment), and some of these are passed on the compiler command-line but not as -D options.  I'd prefer to use these existing ones since 1) they're created automatically; 2) I won't typo one of them differently for one of the compilers; 3) the same convention could be followed by other writers - or by me, on some other project - making code more portable.

Is there a way to automate passing them to the compiler as #defines?

(Eclipse Indigo, CrossPack-AVR-20100115, & Mac OS 10.6.8)

---

Edit:

As a work-around I've written a pre-build script that creates a header file to #define the build-time environment variables:

```
printenv | awk 'BEGIN{print "/***  AUTO-GENERATED FILE -- DO NOT EDIT.  ***/\n";} {sub(/^/, "#define "); sub(/=/, "  "); print; }' >${CWD}/../src/buildtime-environment.h
```

[image: Screenshot of Build Steps dialog]

It works well enough with two caveats:

1. It's fragile - it has "special-knowledge" of my project directory structure.
2. Hovering over one of those macros in the IDE editor, the macro-expansion tool-tip may show an out-of-date value for the macro, potentially causing you to chase a ghost if you forget this and believe the tool-tip.

*(I'll leave this a comment until/unless I give up on finding a solution).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any reference to doing this any other way - or any way at all, really.  So I've generalized my pre-build step to look for a script in the source directory and run it if it exists:

```
if [ -e ../src/avr-prebuild ];  then ../src/avr-prebuild;fi
```

That can do pretty much anything, and is easily customized on a per-project basis.  It doesn't address either of the caveats I wrote in my comment.  That it knows my directory structure isn't terrible, and it encourages me keep them consistent.  The fact that the tool-tip within eclipse doesn't stay up to date is a little more serious but I can live with it.  After I've been fooled a couple more times, I'll probably remember!

Comment: This is the best I've come up with so far. I'm still open to other suggestions, though.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure this answers your question (and I realize it's an old question) but have you looked at the Environment tab of the Run configuration? You can add a new environment variable based on an existing variable. For example in the image below I have a string substitution variable I created named "sb", I can let the compiler know about this variable by adding it to the Environment tab of the Run configuration. Then inside my code I could get to the value of this variable with getenv("sb_scope"). Also it makes sb_scope available to the compiler build process. In general the purpose of this area is to make any variable Eclipse is aware of, available to your host OS environment.

[Shameless Plug] A full demo of this is in the "Demo:String Substitution Variables" clip of Module 3 "Eclipse Variables" in my  Pluralsight course [Eclipse Guided Tour Part 2](http://pluralsight.com/courses/eclipse-guided-tour-part2). [/Shameless Plug]

[image: screen shot of adding new environment variable]